# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/websocket/ClientEndpointConfig$Configurator from StandardWebsocketClient

Tags: java, spring, websocket

I need to write websocket client.
I started following this tutorial: [https://github.com/eugenp/tutorials/blob/master/spring-boot/src/main/java/org/baeldung/websocket](https://github.com/eugenp/tutorials/blob/master/spring-boot/src/main/java/org/baeldung/websocket/)

and after run StomClient I received:

> ```
>     java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/websocket/ClientEndpointConfig$Configurator
> ```
>
> at WebSocketTester.testConnection(WebSocketTester.java:16)
>
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   javax.websocket.ClientEndpointConfig$Configurator     at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)     at
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)     ... 23 more

My pom only have this dependencies:

```
    <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-websocket</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-messaging</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

Client and session handler are copied from github under attached link.
Exception is thrown from this line `WebSocketClient client = new StandardWebSocketClient();` in client class

Comment: Are your dependencies on your classpath when you run your application?

Answer (score 12):

The Spring Boot Starter for WebSockets has the dependencies you need:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-websocket</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 11):

Try adding the following dependency. It worked for me.

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>org.glassfish.tyrus.bundles</groupId>
     <artifactId>tyrus-standalone-client</artifactId>
     <version>1.9</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: project tyrus is the JSR 356: Java API for WebSocket - Reference Implementation. https://tyrus-project.github.io/  (current version 1.17)

Answer (score 3):

Was getting same error. Resolved it by adding below dependency.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.websocket</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.websocket-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: javax.websocket api is only the specification don't have full implementation you may need to take the jar file tyrus-standalone-client-1.9.jar

Comment: This dependency will allow the code to compile but because this dependency only define an API, it cannot be a solution to the problem as stated...because it's a runtime problem.